# What are the "real-world" solutions for not duplicating data in microservices?

Tags: microservices, denormalization, consistency

Suppose that I have a microservice for messaging. The microservice knows how to send emails. The service have templates of emails that have some sort of "template engine" like pugjs, and can replace data in the body of the message.

I have an user service (used for authentication/authorization for example), and a bank account service (each user have one). Between the User microservice and Bank Account microservice it's clear that we don't have to duplicate any data than de user's uuid.

But I want now to send every day a message to each user with their account statement. The Messaging microservice needs data from the User microservice and the Bank Account microservice.

Okay... This is a **small** case of the real world. Now I know that to have the benefits of **decoupled** microservices I must follow some rules:

- I can't share databases between microservices
- I can't make synchronous requests between microservices

Okay... I can use a broker and each time a new user is created/updated the Messaging microservice can store that data. But really, this is a stupid thing:

- I don't want to have inconsistency with this data, and keeping things sync is hard
- The **development time and complexity** of the Messaging Microservice must now consider: listen and extract the relevant data from events, keep data consistent about other domains/services, managing the saved data on database
- And think about a Messaging microservice. Really I must store all the data needed to parse the templates?

**I read a lot** about microservices and people creating rules for their simple examples. But I never really saw a good explanation and real-world examples like above.

So how to have the microservices above without data duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your domain example I would not let the message service know anything about bank or user details. Instead the message service should just receive instructions to send messages to recipients along with the given content. I would use a dedicated scheduled job (maybe implemented as an account notification service) that performs the work of acquiring the user and account data from the corresponding services, compiles the information for the message service and instructs it to actually send the messages. This introduces another "higher level, business purpose entity/service" but allows you to keep a clear separation of concerns.

In general it will happen frequently that your "basic" domain services are used by another service that represents a specific business purpose and requires their data. Dependency in itself is not a bad thing as long as concerns are seperated clearly and interfaces versioned, changes communicated etc.

Don't forget the whole idea of microservices is for allowing teams to have dedicated responsibilities with clear interfacing. It is about organization as much as it is about architecture.

Comment: Great! So, based on this solution, can I talk about microservices "classes"? Something like: core microservices and compound microservices. I see these classes depending on the degree of volatility (scheduled jobs for example) and integration (it uses other microservices to exist) of microservices.

Comment: You could, but in reality there may not be as much black and white but a lot of gray. Cutting the responsibilities for services right is the biggest challenge for implementing any domain. You have to weigh size and separation of responsibilities against organizational overhead for the teams involved as well as scalability  requirements and deployment complexities (the deployment of every service should be able to scale separately).